# mongodb: count/size of a query array

Tags: mongodb, count, mongodb-query

How do I get the size .count of a returned array

```
db.students.distinct('class_id')
```

This query will get back a array, how do I get the size/length/count of this array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember this is javascript code, thus you can get the count of an array using `length`.

`db.students.distinct('class_id').length`

Answer (score 3):

```
db.students.distinct('class_id').length
```